# React JS: How to parse JSX in string?

Tags: css, reactjs, string, jsx, react-props

I have a component **Example** which accepts a `string` as a prop and **styles** it by wrapping it in a **container** having some **CSS** classes.

This is what **Example** looks like:

```
interface Props {
  text: string;
}

const Example: React.FC<Props> = ({ text, }) => (
  <span className="class-a class-b class-c">
    {text}
  </span>
);
```

I'm using **Example** in **Info** Component as follows:

```
const Info: React.FC = () => (
  <div className="class-x class-y class-z">
    <p>
      I am a simple statement
      <Example text=" but I need some styling" />
      !!!!
    </p>
  </div>
);
```

Now, this **Info** component is used in **Parent** component as follows:

```
const Parent: React.FC = () => (
  <Info />
);
```

**Challenge:**
I need to make this **Info** component **re-usable** as follows:

```
const myJSON = {
  val1: "I am a simple statement <Example text=" but I need some styling" 
        />!!!!",
  val2: "Another statement <Example text=" but I need some styling" 
        />!!!!",
}
const Parent: React.FC = () => (
  <Info data={myJSON.va1l} />
  <Info data={myJSON.va2l} />
```

Now, what happening is that **React** is unable to **parse Example** as a component in the prop and **displays** it as follows in the browser:

```
I am a simple statement <Example text=" but I need some styling" />!!!!
Some other statement <Example text=" with this styling" />!!!!
Another again <Example text=" another styling" />!!!!
```

Is there any way or library to make React parse the  as a component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could change your approach to use `children props`

```
const Parent: React.FC = () => (
  <Info>I am a simple statement <Example text=" but I need some styling" />!!!!"</Info>

   <Info>"Some other statement <Example text=" with this styling" />!!!!"</Info>
   <Info>"Another again <Example text=" another styling" />!!!!" </Info>
);

const Example: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => (
    <span className="class-a class-b class-c">
       {children}
    </span>
);

const Info: React.FC = () => (
  <div className="class-x class-y class-z">
    <p>
      I am a simple statement
      <Example>{children}</Example>
      !!!!
    </p>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I am actually this statement from a JSON, so can't really use as a child prop

Comment: An edit has been made to my question, please check that.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the `children` prop is for.
When putting elements within a components JSX like so :

```
const Parent: React.FC = () => (
    <Info>
        I am a simple statement
        <Example text=' but I need some styling' />
        !!!!
    </Info>
);
```

The content will be sent to the `children` prop automatically by React, which can be used within your component :

```
const Info: React.FC = ({ children }) => (
    <div className='class-x class-y class-z'>
        <p>{children}</p>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: I am actually this statement from a JSON, so can't really use as a child prop.

Comment: Oh... this whole thing is a string ? Do you have any control over what this backend is sending to you ?

Comment: I'm maintaining the JSON at client side with lot of key value pairs of long strings having the JSX defined in them. It's not feasible for me to write all that content in component.

Comment: An edit has been made to my question, please check that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReactDomServer.renderToString()` method. It converts React components to string. You can find the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring).

---

### The implementation isn't perfect but it does render the content in the innermost child.

### Parent Component

```
export default function App() {
  let content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Example text="but I need some styling" />
  );

  content += " This is extra string";

  return <Info content={JSON.stringify(content)} />;
}
```

Here you can convert the React component into a string and concatenate any string you may want to. If you get the component already inside a string, then I suggest you use Regex to extract the component out.

### Child Component

```
const Info = ({ content }) => {
  return <Example text={content} />;
};
```

Once you have the component `stringified` you can pass it as a `prop`.

### Inner most Child

```
const Example = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <span
      className="class-a class-b class-c"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }}
    />
  );
};
```

In this component you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` method to set HTML via code. Check out the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

---

As already suggested this is really not a good approach and will leave you vulnerable to `cross-site scripting (XXS)` attacks. I suggest that you change the `JSON` response you are getting if you have control over the backend.